# How do I resolve this error when using Scala.js to generate logic for Screep?

Tags: scala, screeps, scala.js

I am attempting to use Scala.js to generate logic for screep, but I am running into the following error when I try to import the generated javascript code:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Object' of undefined
at eval:1:358
at screeplogic:45:322
at m:4:3096
at console:45
at Object.c.runCode:4:6811
```

To start with, I created a bare-bones Scala.js project:

https://github.com/Voltir/screepslogic

I then linked my screep account to that repo, using the "generated" folder as the linked folder to import into the game.

To get that error, I start a custom simulation and then in the screep console and do a simple `require("screeplogic")`

Comment: IIUC, you're making a node.js module in Scala.js?

Comment: I can't say for certain, but I suspect that the screep game engine is built entirely in node, so it is reasonable to think that the code I am uploading (a fullOpt'd Scala.js file) is being parsed by an eval call in node.

Comment: Also, the link to the screep game is here: http://screeps.com/

Comment: I am not affliated with Screeps, but if I had to guess I suspect that this node module may be involved: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace indicates that the error is not in Screeps code, but in yours:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Object' of undefined
at eval:1:358
at screeplogic:45:322  <-- here it is
```

If you check the specified place in `screeplogic:45:322` you can see that your  transpiler tries to invoke the generated closure function with `this` variable:

```
(function() { ....... }).call(this);
```

But in the simulation mode the global context is not stored in `this` so this invokation fails. If you pass `global` variable explicitly, then everything seems to work fine:

```
(function() { ....... }).call(global);
```

Comment: The output of that transpiler is supposed to be given `this` in all circumstances, including in a Node-like environment where `global` is the global scope. (I know because I wrote ite.) One of the very first things it does it find out what the global scope is that way: https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/blob/master/tools/scalajsenv.js#L15-L19 which is supposed to detect the `global` case. It works great in a vanilla Node.js instance (we test this in our CI). There seems to be something weird in the Screep environment that makes this logic flawed, but what? I've no idea.

Comment: I went ahead and manually applied the suggested change to the generated javascript, just to see if I could get it working and it does... something. I wrote a quick test page to check what the generated code does, and sure enough it does generate a "module.exports" which in this case, *should* be a function... however in screeps land, while it no longer throws an error, requrie("screepslogic") returns an object.. and I can't for the life of me figure out what the keys of that object are.

Comment: Edit: also, it is my understanding that require("screepslogic") will return whatever "module.exports" is defined as.

Comment: Another thing I tried was manually editing the generated source code by removing that last '.call(this)' and adding module.exports to the start of the script such that it now looks like module.exports = (function(){...}) and this also does... something. It appears the call method is defined on this new thing, but doing require("screeplogic).call(global) returns undefined when in screep script / console mode.

Comment: Screeps has two runtime modes - server-side which implies running under Node.js, and the simulation which is browser-only. Due to that, this transpiled code will work fine when uploaded onto the server but is broken while running in the browser because of `this === undefined`.

Comment: OK so you may be able to make it work without actually editing the code emitted by Scala.js, simply by prefixing it with `var __ScalaJSEnv = {global: global};`. This is the official "configuration" of Scala.js to make it use the `global` you want it to use, and not whatever it tries to figure out by itself.